# PHP MySQL - How do I obtain the id of the result of the last Insert statement without a second query?

Tags: php, mysql, networking, select

How do I obtain the id of the result of the last Insert statement without a second query?

I am aware I could select the last row of the database to get what I'm looking for... sometimes. The issue is if two users are inserting at the same time I'm worried that they may get the wrong results.

Pseudo Example Code:

```
User 1 - Insert Record A
User 1 - Select last Record
User 1 - Record A Selected
```

Pseudo Multi-user Problem:

```
User 1 - Insert Record A
User 2 - Insert Record B
User 1 - Select last Record
**User 1 - Record B Selected**
User 2 - Select last Record
User 2 - Record B Selected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not occur, when the users use different connections. That should always be the case on different requests. But even within the same script, utilizing *different* connections, ensures the separation.

Prove:

```
$connection_for_user1 = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test');
$connection_for_user2 = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test');

$result_for_user1 = $connection_for_user1->query("INSERT INTO test_table (data) VALUES ('A')");
$result_for_user2 = $connection_for_user2->query("INSERT INTO test_table (data) VALUES ('B')");

$record_id_for_user1 = $connection_for_user1->insert_id;
$record_id_for_user2 = $connection_for_user2->insert_id;

echo "User 1: record $record_id_for_user1\n";
echo "User 2: record $record_id_for_user2\n";
```

Result:

```
User 1: record 1
User 2: record 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysql_insert_id()` or `mysqli_insert_id` to fetch the last inserted id

Comment: Right, however my worry is if 5 people are using the function at the same time isn't there a possibility that someone or multiple people will receive incorrect results since MySQL is answering multiple requests?
Thanks for the response!

Comment: It will return the id from the current connection. So if you and 2 other people are using the script, your result will be the id from your last insert, and the others will get the insert ids form their last insert. if that makes sense!